# Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer play mp3 from offset before playing state

Tags: ios, mp3, media, audiostreamer

I did not found solution for one issue: how to play mp3 file from offset immideately?

I can only play file then send **-(void)seekToTime:** but in this case sound begins and interrupts then begins from defined offset.

I tried to apply **seekToTime** method on **ASStatusChangedNotification** (in different cases of **AudioStreamerState**) but there were without result.

upd: I think that may set time offset after the file began streaming (before playing). But how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a method to seek to the desired time that I run after `[streamer start]`:

`while(streamer.bitRate == 0) {
        sleep(1);
}`

If you're concerned about waiting too long, you can add a time out: either a count of times through the loop, or set a start time and compare it to the current time to break out of the loop.

This blog post has another take: 
http://www.saygoodnight.com/2009/08/streaming-audio-to-the-iphone-starting-at-an-offset/

Comment: Thanks you, I solved it's similar. But the example in blog is not good solution...

Comment: It doesn't work as-is because some of the instance variables and calculations have changed, but following a similar approach works fine. One thing you have to keep in mind is that the first time the bit-rate is set it may be inaccurate (in fact in all my trials it is wrong, and obviously wrong: always under 1.0) .. so if you wait until bitRate > 1.0 it works better.